# Fix "configure: error: cannot find python-config for /usr/bin/python"

Tags: python, configure

I'm trying to install SU2 from source on Ubuntu 22.04 and i have a problem regarding the configure command. Running it gives:
`configure: error: cannot find python-config for /usr/bin/python`

However, I have indeed python and python3 but somehow i do not have the python-config. In fact:

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

which python3
/usr/bin/python3

which python-config
Nothing.
```

Furthermore, the $PATH should be correct as it contains `/usr/bin/python`. I think the question may be silly but I haven't found great answer on other threads.
Thank you for the help

Comment: Try installing the python-dev package from your OS repos. What linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and python-dev package was already installed

Comment: Ok, make sure you install the appropriate version for the interpreter you are using, for example `python3.10-dev` if you are using python 3.10...

Comment: According to the package manager on my ubuntu 22.04 box, the `python-config` command comes from the `python3-dev` or `python2-dev` package.